# Trying to understand an equality between sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Consider the following equivalence class:
$${[\mathbb{N}]_s} = \{ A \in P(\mathbb{Z}) : |A| = |A \cup \mathbb{N}| \wedge |\mathbb{N}| = |A \cup \mathbb{N}|\} $$

So, $A$ must be infinite set with the power of $\aleph_0$.

I'm trying to understand the statement below. The set in the middle isn't very clear to me. And apparntly it's power is $\aleph$.
$$\{ A \cup {\mathbb{N}_{even}}:A \subseteq {\mathbb{N}_{odd}}\}  \subseteq {[\mathbb{N}]_s}$$

I'll appreciate an explanation to make it clear.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did you use the [infinite-groups] tag?

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I replaced some instances of $|$ with $:$ in the question, to improve readability. Feel free to change it back if you're uncomfortable with the changes.

Comment: Thanks @user18921, don't mind at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>First of all, writing that $\aleph$ is **equal** to that set is false. It is equal to the cardinality of that set, yes. But not to that set specifically.</del> (The remark is related to [a previous revision](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/615606/4).)

Now, the set is the set all of subsets of $\Bbb N$ which include all the even numbers (from $\Bbb N$), to see that it is so note that every subset of $\Bbb N$ including the even numbers can be written as a subset of the odd numbers union the set of all even numbers.

This shows that there is an injection from $\mathcal P(\Bbb N_{odd})$ into $[\Bbb N]_s$, and since the former set has size $2^{\aleph_0}$, or $\aleph$, so much the latter.

Comment: Can you expand your statement about the injection please?

Comment: Andre, $A\mapsto A\cup\Bbb N_{even}$.

Comment: OK, I think it's more clear to me now. Cheers